# mysql: select * from table but with unique value in specific column

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a sql table  with this structure

```
id,userid, name, date1, date2
```

so i have rows like this

```
1, 1, name33, 2018-10-12, 2018-10-13
2, 1, name22, 2018-10-12, 2018-10-13 
3, 1, name90, 2018-10-12, 2018-10-13

4, 2, name11, 2018-10-14, 2018-10-15
5, 2, name12, 2018-10-14, 2018-10-15 
6, 2, name30, 2018-10-14, 2018-10-15
```

what i want to get is this

```
 userid, date1, date2
1, 2018-10-12, 2018-10-13
2, 2018-10-14, 2018-10-15
```

for each user just 1 row (so dont show rows that date1 and date2 are same)

i tried this but it doesnt work

```
SELECT * (DISTINCT date1,date2) FROM orders
```

Comment: What if two users have the same dates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `DISTINCT` in wrong way; it is not a function. Following query would get unique combinations of `userid, date1, date2`

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  userid, 
  date1, 
  date2 
FROM orders
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to `SELECT *` as mentioned in the title and sample query, you can use `GROUP BY` to achieve this - though a word of caution, your, non-aggregated columns will be showing some kind of arbitrary values and if you have [`ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) turned on this will throw an error:

```
SELECT *
FROM `orders`
GROUP BY userid, date1, date2
```

To use `GROUP BY` properly you should only select grouped columns or use aggregate functions on the other columns.  For instance, this would get `DISTINCT userid, date1 and date2` values, while showing all the `name` values for each group as a comma separated list:

```
SELECT userid, date1, date2, GROUP_CONCAT(`name`) as grouped_names
FROM `orders`
GROUP BY userid, date1, date2
```

Answer (score -1):

`Select userid,distinct date1,distinct date2 from table group by userid`

> This would rather group all the userids with distinct dates.